# Return array or null result for application of a command to a list

Tags: java, null

I have such method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T, K> K[] toArray(ITemplateCommand<T, K> command, List<T> templates) {
    if (null == templates) {
        return (K[]) Array.newInstance(command.getClassOfK(), 0);
    }
    K[] array = (K[]) Array.newInstance(command.getClassOfK(), templates.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < templates.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = command.buildTemplate(templates.get(i));
    }
    return array;
}
```

Originally I had `return null` in block `if (null == templates)` but FindBugs recommended not to return null but `array` instead.

I am curious - should I leave it as it now or return to `return null` line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real answer to your question is not in the code that returns `null`, but in code that uses that result.

If returned `null` is significant signal and you have to execute some code based on that value (other than simply avoiding NPE) then you should return `null`. If code calling `toArray` could and would happily function properly if you return empty array instance, then returning empty array is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

In general I always believe that although we use software like FindBugs to make us think and receive hints where improvement of our code might be usefull in the end it is up to us to decide. If you consider your code is better to understand the way you wrote it, you should keep it that way.

Answer (score 3):

It's a recommended good practice to return an empty collection instead of `null`. If you return `null`, callers need an extra null-check when using the function.

`null` is a non-functional value. `null` is special. You can iterate over any collection, but not a `null` collection. If I can trust that a method returning a collection will never return `null`, then I can iterate over it without an extra null-check. If a method may return `null`, the extra null-check will inconvenience all callers.

This is not say that a method should never ever return `null` for a collection. It just says that when you choose to return `null`, you should have a good justification for that (it does happen too).

To conclude, if you have a specific reason to return `null`,
then by all means, return `null`.
Otherwise, follow the good advice and return an empty array.